# Angular router route guard or (de) resolve

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

I extensively use resolvers in Angular and they are great. They resolve my data, when I navigate deeper into the nested router. However, I would also like to deresolve routes, meaning when I move back up the router tree, I would like to execute code.

**Architectural description**

Basically I have a complex header menu, which lives in a submodule, has a public facing service API, which has public functions, to which I can pass state. Aka. I have many companies, which have many contracts. If I move down the router to a company, it will send the company to the header, which will caluclate its new state and display it. If I move further down, it will additionally send the contract and calculate new state. Now if I move back up the router to company level, I would like to remove the contract, by "deresolving".

The header service can receive input from multiple modules in the application, which are all lazy loaded, thus I cannot include them in the header on app boot. The only other option is to make a public facing header API, which everybody can dependancy inject and then pass state.

**Scenario real life** (where C is the child of B and B is the child of A).

Resolvers:

[A,B,C]

Routing:

A -> B -> C -> B -> A

Firing order:

A(resolve),B(resolve),C(resolve)

**Scenario which I want** (where C is the child of B and B is the child of A).

Resolvers:

[A,B,C]

Routing:

A -> B -> C -> B -> A

Firing order:

A(resolve),B(resolve),C(resolve),**A(de-resolve),B(de-resolve),A(de-resolve)**

**In short:** I would like to deresolve a route in Angular, is this possible?

Or any other good ideas on how to execute required functionality, when moving up the routing tree?

Comment: There's no such thing; you can see the hooks in e.g. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards. Could you give some *context* on how you'd want to use this?

Comment: [Edit] the question; comments are ephemeral.

Comment: When you go back, you are resolving new route. No matter if it is going down or up in route hierarchy. It will be always navigation to new route.